# Why is every request/login ballooning memory allocation to .net API?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, memory-leaks, .net-7.0

[image]

Those APIs get a request from a Service Worker every 10 seconds, service worker logs in via JWT (Identity), then calls one endpoint to check whether there are any new emails marked in the DB to be sent. It always returns nothing as there aren't any emails to be sent. It repeats the process every 10 seconds. Every 10 seconds the token is updated (worker logs in every time)

I started those APIs last night, this morning QA one grew to 4.5 gigs. And it keeps growing. I don't think there is a memory leak, I read some articles about people having similar issues and most replies are "this is normal, GC will eventually collect". But GC doesn't want to collect automatically it seems and keeps this memory allocated which can't be used by other services.

What should I look at? I tried profiling with dotMemory - all I can see is that GC runs, and moves stuff from Heap0 to Heap1 and Heap2 and keeps it there.

Any advice or anything I can add to help you help me diagnose what's going on?

EDIT:

This is what happens over time, Forcing GC moves everything to Heap Generation 2 and doesn't seem to ever clear it:

[image]

Comment: If none requests more memory.... What if you run another process that needs more memory? Then you should see some action to free the unused memory

Comment: @Steve I ran a blazor calendar project, once it grew over 3GB, the QAAPI was reduced to 1.5GB... So it collected/released memory - but still, why does it grow so large and why does it not release it earlier?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should review your design, why do you need to make calls every 10 seconds If there are no expected records, you could think of increasing the time. Or you could also use a different design like using SQL dependency, so whenever there is a change in a database table, your application will be notified. you can read about it by Google search.

As you have not shared the code and complete details now coming to the possibilities in your current application. there could be fee potential causes behind the increase in memory usage.

you need to check for memory leaks, you have to make sure that you profile your application during its normal operation to capture the growing memory consumption. You also need to review your code closely as well.

If objects are retained long in the memory, then there could be event subscriptions, caching mechanisms, or any other factors that prevent objects from being garbage collected. Check for event handlers who are unsubscribed when they are no longer needed.

As you are dealing with the database, you need to monitor the database queries and also ensure that resources like connections, data readers, and other database-related objects are properly disposed of after use.

If you are using some third-party libraries then you also need to check their's updates, documentation, and forums as well.

Load testing also can help you in your investigation.